# Cannot get Data from API via VB.Net

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, api

I try to get Reverse Geocodes from API web. But It found error 403 forbidden.

> this is my VB.Net Code (Backend Code)

```
        <HttpPost>
        Public Function Location(ByVal DataJSON As Location) As JsonResult
            Dim LocationValue As Location = New Location With {
                .Lat = DataJSON.Lat,
                .Lon = DataJSON.Lon
            }


            Dim getrequest As HttpWebRequest
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse
            Dim reader As StreamReader

            getrequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=" & LocationValue.Lat & "&lon=" & LocationValue.Lon & "&zoom=18&addressdetails=1&extratags=1"), HttpWebRequest)

            response = DirectCast(getrequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) 


            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()) 


            Dim ReverseLocate As New Location

            Dim rawData As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim jResults As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(rawData)
            ReverseLocate.Place = jResults("address[0]")

            Return Json(ReverseLocate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End Function
```

> Error reach here

```
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

> And my AJAX function

```
 var Locate = new Object(); <!-- GET Required Data -->
    Locate.Lat = Lat;
    Locate.Lon = Lon
    $.ajax({
        url: "/home/Location",
        data: JSON.stringify(Locate),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {
           alert('error')
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.errorcode == 0) {
             alert('ok')
            }
        }
    })
```

Who can to help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: 403 generally means `forbidden` as in you do not have access to perform the action. Does the API require some form of access token for validation?

Comment: Actually, from a very basic check, it looks as though you may need to use `https` and not `http`

Comment: Currently, this api has a limit of 1 request per second, maybe if you are doing more than 1 request per second you should be request limited. Relevant docs https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/